# is there a function in lua to return the size of table

Tags: lua

I tried to use "table.getn" and "#" to get number of columns , but the problem is where i have a table that contains a "nil" in the last column he didn't count it as an existant column and he returns error because the table didn't respect the condition;
here is the example : ( second row return the error and when i replace the last nil in the row with a string , it return valid row number)

```
liste_profils_modbus = { 
    {"ON/OFF","register",12300,nil,1,nil,nil,1,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,"harmony",nil,"0=OFF,1=ON"},
    {"Calefacción agua proporcional      %","register",12407,nil,nil,nil,nil,14,nil,nil,"%",nil,nil,nil,nil,nil},
    {"Tipo de calefacción por    agua","register",8531,nil,1,nil,nil,1,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,"harmony",nil,"0=ON/OFF,1=Proporcional"},
}

local function checkModbusProfileRows(row)
local valid_register_types = {"register", "inputregister", "coil", "discretinput"}
local valid_modbus_datatype = {"uint16", "int16", "uint32", "int32", "float32", "uint64", "int64", "float64"}
local valid_write_mode = {"lasttouch", "harmony", "blindwrite", "writeonly", "nil"}

assert(row ~= nil, string.format("no data provided"))
assert(type(row) == "table", string.format("Data must be a table"))
assert(#row == 16, string.format("Data must have 16 elements , got %s", #row))

end

-- Check if an item is in a table
function table.contains(table, item)
   for _, value in pairs(table) do
        if value == item then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

-- Iterate over each row and validate
```

for _, row in ipairs(liste_profils_modbus) do
local isValid, errorMsg = pcall(checkModbusProfileRows, row)
if not isValid then
log("Error in row: ", errorMsg)
else
log("Rows are valid")
end
end`